# Laravel 8 relationship search returning empty result

Tags: laravel, datatables, relationship

I have this query:

```
 $orders = Order::with(['company', 'products', 'user', 'status', 'seller'])->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->select('orders.*');
```

And it returns the relevant results as expected in a yajra datatable instance.

Now I would like to narrow down this result even more. I use it this way:

```
 $orders = $orders->whereHas('user', function ($q) use ($request){                
                 $q->searchFullName($request->seller);
             });
```

I have created a scope in the model and it works for another function on my website. However it returns no results when calling it like that.

Even if I call the whereHas using a where statement, still the result is empty:

```
 $orders = $orders->whereHas('user', function ($q) use ($request){                
                 $q->where('first_name', 'like', '%'.$request->seller.'%');
             });
```

The seller parameter is not empty. Even if I use a hardcoded string, the results are always empty.

The searchFullName method:

```
public  function scopesearchFullName($query, $value){
        return $query->where('first_name', 'LIKE', "%$value%")
                     ->orWhere('middle_name', 'LIKE', "%$value%")
                     ->orWhere('last_name', 'LIKE', "%$value%");
    }
```

Full controller:

```
public function listOrdersData(Request $request)
    {
        if(!$request->ajax())
            return Redirect::route('/');
   
        $loggedUser = Auth::user();
    
        if($loggedUser->hasRole('Super Administratör'))
            $orders = Order::with(['company', 'products', 'user', 'status', 'seller'])->orderBy('orders.id', 'DESC')->select('orders.*'); 
        else
            $orders = Order::with(['company', 'products', 'user', 'status', 'seller'])->where('company_id', $loggedUser->company_id)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->select('orders.*'); 
         
        if (!empty($request->seller) && $request->seller != 'all') {       
     
            $orders = $orders->whereHas('user', function ($q) use ($request){
              
                 $q->searchFullName($request->seller);
             });
        }
     
        return DataTables::of($orders) 
            ->addColumn('products', function($orders) {
                $products = "";
                foreach($orders->products as $product)               
                   $products = $products . $product->name . "<br>"; 
                
                return $products;
            })
            ->editColumn('company', function($orders){ return $orders->company->name; })            
            ->editColumn('price', '{{$price}} kr')   
            ->editColumn('user', function($orders){
                return $orders->user->full_name;
            }) 
            ->addColumn('seller', function($orders){
                return $orders->seller->full_name;
            })   
            ->addColumn('status', function($orders){
                return '<span class="chip lighten-4 purple purple-text">'. $orders->status->localized . '</span>';
            }) 
            ->addColumn('contract', '<a href="/download/{{$scrive_id}}"><i class="material-icons">file_download</i></a>')   
            ->addColumn('edit', '<a href="/editOrder/{{$id}}"><i class="material-icons">edit</i></a>')        
            ->rawColumns(['products', 'status', 'edit', 'contract'])          
      

  ->make(true);
}
```

Comment: can you searchFullName method and also show full controller method

Comment: @JohnLobo I added both

Comment: try  $orders = $orders->whereHas('user', function ($q) use ($request){                
                 $q->where(function($q) use ($request){
     $q->searchFullName($request->seller);
     })
             });

Comment: No this didnt work. Still empty results and no errors.

Comment: try adding log and check it reaches inside wherehas

Comment: @JohnLobo yes it does get inside whereHas.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234690/discussion-between-john-lobo-and-m33ts4k0z).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with scope method

```
public function scopesearchFullName($query, $value){
    return $query->where('first_name', 'LIKE', "%".$value."%")
                 ->orWhere('middle_name', 'LIKE', "%".$value."%")
                 ->orWhere('last_name', 'LIKE', "%".$value."%");
}
```

Also make sure that only those user record returns who has orders.

Also for searching sellers  order

```
$orders = $orders->whereHas('seller', function ($q) use ($request){
          
             $q->searchFullName($request->seller);
         });
```

so in Order model

```
public function seller()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'seller_id', 'id');
}
```

Comment: Yeah some mistakes where made here. The reason that I wasnt getting a result was that in the order table, the user I looked for, didnt have any orders. Then since I use the same table for customers and sellers, I created a new relationship in the orders model in order to match seller_id to the id in the users table. That solved the issue.